# emailing with php

Tags: php, email

What's wrong with this...? I don't get an email back...
Also, does the from address have to be a real address? If I run this on a computer that doesn't have Outlook Express, will it not work? How can I make it work on computers like that?

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Test php</title>
</head>

<?php
$to = "asjjohnson127@aim.com";
$subject = "testing php emailing";
$from = "asjjohnson127@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $from";
$message = "Your username is " . $_POST['username'];
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    echo "Mail Sent.";
else
    echo "Problem with mail.";
?>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your running the script on a local server you'll need to configure the php.ini look for the following and change to your ISP's SMTP server.

```
[mail function]
SMTP = smtp.isp.net
sendmail_from = me@isp.net
```

You code will send email, its an issue with your SMTP configuration.

Another way to do it is set SMTP to localhost then use a SMTP service http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html usually runs on port 25 If I remember correctly.

Comment: can you tell me what the php.ini is, and how to know if it's a local server?

Comment: Are you running PHP from your home or work machine? PHP.ini is the PHP configuration file. Are you running this on a webhost?

Comment: I got an account from Free Hostia and put it there, I'm at home, and I want it to work on some computers in a lab.

Comment: You may want to ask "Free Hostia" (whoever they are :) if they allow PHP-mailing. I know of some free webhosters who deactivate mailing to prevent spam.

Comment: An alternative to modifying php.ini (php config file) is to use ini_set in your script (call these before calling mail() )...
ini_set('SMTP', 'smtp.gmail.com');
ini_set('smtp_port', '25');

Answer (score 0):

You have to send mail from a machine that can be accessed directly from outside - via IP or URL. Having Outlook has absolutely nothing to do with that.

Comment: what do you mean by "accessed directly from outside"?
I just mentioned Outlook because in computer labs, if I click an "email me" link, it'll say you have to configure Outlook before sending an email.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is an email client, you need to connect to an email server, the easy way is to buy a cheap hosting account as this replaces the option where you have to setup your own email server.(Some ISP block port 25 to prevent spam)